# Sails JS : How to return a value from a service

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sails.js

I am creating a service in sails js. I want to update the value of totalCount before returning it. But the problem is when the return is in the callback of the async.series I am getting an undefined when I'm invoking it. How should I do this?

```
var totalCount = 0;

    async.series([
        function getProducts(cb_series){
            Inventory.find({sku_id : sku_id, bay_id : bay_id})
                .then(function(inventory_items){

                    async.each(inventory_items, function(item, cb_each){
                        totalCount = totalCount + item.physical_count;
                        cb_each();
                    }, function(err){
                        if(err)
                            console.log(err);

                        cb_series();
                    });             
                });
        }
    ], function returnResult(err, cb){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);

        return totalCount;
    });
```

Comment: WTH are you using `async.each` for a synchronous summation?

Comment: Because the result of a find is an array. It will return more than 1 instance that will match my criteria and I am adding all of those that's why I'm using async each

Comment: Yes, `inventory_items` is an array. But you can loop over that with a simple `for` loop, no need for `async`?

Comment: Oh. Ok thanks. When should I use async each?

Comment: Only when the "loop body" is asynchronous. But as you're using promises, actually never.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do.  But you probably want to pass totalCount out in a callback like this:

```
function getProducts(callback){
    Inventory.find({sku_id : sku_id, bay_id : bay_id}).then(
        function(inventory_items){
            callback(null, inventory_items.length)
        }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        });
}
```

If there is an error, it will call back with the error as it's first parameter, so do a null check on that.  If the first parameter is null, then the second parameter will be the length of your array.

If you'd rather return all of the products and not just the length (as the name of the function implies), then it's very similar:

```
function getProducts(callback){
    Inventory.find({sku_id : sku_id, bay_id : bay_id}).then(
        function(inventory_items){
            callback(null, inventory_items)
        }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        });
}
```

You'd use it like this for the first case:

```
getProducts(function(err, productCount) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    } else {
        var totalCount = productCount;
    }
    //etc etc...
}
```

...or this for the second case:

```
getProducts(function(err,products) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    } else {
        var productArray = products;
    }
    //etc etc...
}
```

Comment: Is that the only way? Isn't there any way of getting the result "out of the box"? Can't believe there isn't.

Comment: @patryk  What do you mean "out of the box"?

Comment: in any programming language I used to play with, I never faced a problem, where I'm not able to access variable that was created before, but is in the same function. Unless it was killed somehow, or it's content was changed. I don't understand why in example above, variable "totalCount" isn't available inside function getProducts().

Comment: @Patryk- I'm not sure which one you're referring to, but likely you're _not_ looking in the same function.  I can assure you that Javascript variables are available for access within the function that they were declared, perhaps you're missing something.  I'd be happy to explain what's going on if you're specific.